# How do I create a bootable copy of my operating system on an external HDD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, bootable-media

I have a MacBook Air which I'll be installing Linux on, and want to copy the operating system to an external hard drive so I don't lose my files. I tried using Clonezilla, however it does not show up in the boot menu when I hold Alt while booting. In Disk Utility, it says it's not bootable. When I was cloning it I used `disk-disk` and `disk-to-local-disk`.

Comment: Better, I think, to get VMware Fusion or Parallels (the first is better I think) and run Linux in virtual machine. This will serve your needs well

Comment: I'm asking how to copy my operating system to another hard drive. I don't like Mac OS, and want to get rid of it, not just run a virtual machine with Linux.

Comment: Put your files (data and documents) on a USB Hard Drive if you do not need the OS.  Then set up Linux :  https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-install-linux-on-mac-3637265/

Comment: I'm asking how to create a bootable copy, not how to keep the files.

Comment: Mac Time machine should do what you want, does it have it installed?

Comment: Yes. Will that create a bootable drive copy, or just a file backup?

Comment: [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) will do that, & additionally can put a Recovery partition on the clone drive too.

Comment: Often easier just to do another full install & copy your backup of /home, list of installed apps and maybe some settings from /etc into new install. Be careful on how copy is made. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs. Some tools make perfect copies and are good for restoring, but not duplicating. Also exteral UEFI boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, internal drives boot from /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. Be sure to use UEFI/gpt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi

Comment: Can the UUIDs be duplicate if they are on separate drives and not connected to the same computer? Is that why I can't boot from my external hard drive, because it has the same UUIDs as my internal hard drive?

Comment: I'll try booting it from another computer.